# Need to generate csr.txt and private key.txt using java

Tags: java

I have a scenario where I need to generate csr and display the content of the csr in csr.txt and then create a privatekey and display the content in privatekey.txt in C:\ drive without using openSSL to extract private key

Can this process be achieved using Java ? Can keytool accomplish csr and private key without using openSSL?

I tried using keytool for csr but private key I'm not able to .

```
keytool -genkey -dname "emailAddress=test@aaa.com, OU=Test1, O=Test, L=TestCity, CN=Test" -alias Test -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore test.keystore -storepass changeit

keytool -certreq -alias Test -file "C:\csr.txt" -keystore test.keystore -storepass changeit
```

Comment: Use of keytool is not programming, but `-certreq` should already create a text-format (PEM) file except that you specified a different and presumably wrong alias. keytool cannot export a privatekey, but you can write a program to do so.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, I'm new to certs in java, how to achieve this?

Comment: If you don't like OpenSSL I would choose the KeyStore Explorer (https://keystore-explorer.org/) - generate a keystore, generate a key pair, export csr, export private key - all included and tested. Doing this manually/programmatically would require an external library (Bouncy Castle) and need a lot of experience.

Comment: @MichaelFehr+ KSE is a nice alternative, but export private key as PKCS8 _unencrypted_ (if that's okay) PEM is easy even without Bouncy, just `KeyStore.getKey()` -> `PrivateKey.getEncoded()` -> `Base64.getMimeEncoder().encode()` plus some constant strings (see RFC7468).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: you are fully right, I spoke about the complete task (special on export csr) to recommend KSE [I am been able to do this in plain Java but it's a lot of code and lots of hick ups are waiting for unexperienced programmer :-)]